# php - sustitución de patrones REGEX por cadenas en array

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un bloque de texto con incrustaciones de cadenas similares a "[***]blk_foto_1[***]" y quiero filtrar dicho bloque para que el resultado sea un texto donde se sustituya "[***]blk_foto_1[***]" por "imagen1.jpg", luego he tratado de hacerlo con expresiones regulares pero no logro lo que quiero, y la verdad creo que me voy a morir y aun no comprenderé del todo como funcionan las "regex".
hasta ahora tengo algo así:

```
$cadena = 'lorem vestibulum torquent at [***]blk_foto_1[***] orttitor habitasse mattis [***]blk_foto_2[***] platea taciti';
$patrones = [0=>'/[***]blk_foto_1[***]/', 1=>'/[***]blk_foto_2[***]/'];
$imagenes = [0 => 'imagen1.jpg', 1 => 'imagen2.jpg'];

echo preg_replace($patrones, $imagenes, $cadena);
```

Pero me devuelve exactamente la misma cadena original sin cambios.

Mi expectativa es que la cadena resultante sustituyera '[***]blk_foto_1[***]' por 'imagen1.jpg' y así sucesivamente, donde los índices de $patrones se corresponda con los índices de $imagenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas usar preg_replace para eso. `str_replace` acepta arrays como argumentos:

```
<?php

$cadena = 'lorem vestibulum torquent at [***]blk_foto_1[***] orttitor habitasse mattis [***]blk_foto_2[***] platea taciti';
$patrones = ['[***]blk_foto_1[***]', '[***]blk_foto_2[***]'];
$imagenes = ['imagen1.jpg', 'imagen2.jpg'];

echo str_replace($patrones, $imagenes, $cadena);
```

[Te dejo un fiddle funcionando](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57684645f005b333f002d4a87ae6e7664ebce4e8)

PD: si en realidad lo que quieres reemplazar no es literalmente como nos mostraste, y de verdad necesitas usar una expresión regular, tendrías que escapar los caracteres especiales (* [ y ] para empezar).

Comment: Gracias .. ya lo he resuelto usando la sugerencia de amenadiel, sólo quisiera acotar que tuve normalizar primero los arrays "patrones" y "imagenes" porque necesito que coincidan sus respectivos índices, pues la sustitución tenía que ser en coincidencia de índices y no por el orden natural que trajeran los respectivos arrays... Ya está solucionado .. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: comprendo, entonces usaste una especie de array_sort?

Comment: Si, exacto, ya todo me funionó perfecto, gracias.